# IE float right issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-float

I'm having an issue in IE9 with a span (`span.share`) that I'm trying to `float:right` next to a div that is `float:left` all of this inside a span.

jsfiddle (remember to view in IE): http://jsfiddle.net/MgW6R/2/

This is what it looks like in IE9:

[image]

This is how it should look (and looks like in other browsers):

[image]

**html**

```
<div class="contentWrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <span class="contentItem">
            <a href="javascript: void(0);">
                <img src="http://www.example.com/image1.jpg">
            </a>
            <div class="detailsWrapper">
                <div class="name-date">
                    <span class="date">Jul 04: </span>
                    <span class="userName">Christie</span>
                </div>
                <span class="share"></span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="caption">Watching the fireworks in NY without the crowds, heat and concussion via tv #cahs</div>
            </div>
        </span>
        <span class="contentItem">
            ...
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.contentWrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.content {
    margin-left: 256px;
    padding-top: 14px;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
}   
.contentItem {
    display: inline-block !important;
    margin: 0 14px 0 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.contentItem a {
    display: block;
}
.contentItem img {
    height: 450px;
}
.contentItem .detailsWrapper {
    color: #E3E3E3;
    position: relative;
}
.contentItem .detailsWrapper .name-date {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 0 0;
}
.contentItem .detailsWrapper .share {
    background: url("http://www.connectionsacademy.com/_images/teenWebsite/share-btn-sprite.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    height: 23px;
    width: 91px;
}
.clear { clear: both; }
.contentItem .detailsWrapper .caption {
    margin-top: 10px;
    white-space: normal;
    width: 450px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

**NOTE:**
I originally had `span.share` `position:absolute` but I had to change it because it was causing issues with other elements on the page.

Comment: I have to ask, why are you setting `display:block` in the `span.contentItem`s, but then you have `display:inline-block !important;` in the CSS for the same item...?

Comment: @Kolink there's a lot of jquery on this page, it's jquery setting `display:block` on that element. I've verified that that's not the problem in ie.

Comment: If you're referring to `.name-date`, swap its position with `span.share` on your markup.

Comment: @bfavaretto `.name-date` should be `float:left` and `.share` should be `float:right`

Comment: @bfavaretto switching the elements in the html made no difference

Comment: So I don't know, I don't have IE to test right now. Here is a jsfiddle for others who are trying to help: http://jsfiddle.net/MgW6R/.

Comment: @bfavaretto thank you. I've updated the margin so you can see the whole image and included in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the look of it you need to specify a width at some point. Since they are all set to auto it is taking as much space as it can. I would try setting some specific widths as well as a width of 100% to the `.detailsWrapper`.

This should make sure that width never exceeds the parent, but that also means you need to make sure the part width has bounds.

If the widths are dynamic try using `jQuery` to set them one the image is loaded and use the image width to set the `.contentItem` width and it should ensure that everything stays the same width.

Comment: Yep that was it. I hate to have to set a width but it looks like another IE FAIL. I set `.contentItem { width: 450px; }` and `.detailsWrapper { width: 100%; }`

Answer (score 0):

If container width is unknown, you can use position absolute instead of float for Share button. Just place it right after the image in the flow and set only right coordinate (don't set top). It'll be:

```
.container {position:relative;border:2px solid blue;...}
.button-share {position:absolute;right:0;...}
```

To size container by its contents use display:inline-block|table, float or position:absolute.

Comment: I noted this at the bottom of the question - I've already tried this, and while it works, I can't use this solution because it caused issue with other elements on the page.